# Check if the message author has a role discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a "nitro replacement" for users who don't have it in my server, when someone sends an animated emoji `:test:` and they don't have nitro, the bot deletes the message, then sends the animated emoji.

```
role = ["-『』· -"]
@bot.listen("on_message")
async def nitro(msg):
        if ":" == msg.content[0] and ":" == msg.content[-1] and role in msg.author.roles:
            emoji_name = msg.content[1:-1]
            for emoji in msg.guild.emojis:
                if emoji_name == emoji.name:
                    await msg.channel.send(f"{msg.author.mention}{str(emoji)}")
                    await msg.delete()
```

The bot runs, but for some reason it doesn't work when the  `and role in msg.author.roles:` part is included. It just leaves my `:test:` text there

How the bot should work vs how it does:

[image]

What did i do wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing a list (`role`) to a role object (`msg.author.roles`). This statement will never be true.
You could either get the role, via a getter-function, like

```
role = msg.guild.get_role(id)
```

Or, compare to the role-name

```
role = "-『』· -"
@bot.listen("on_message")
async def nitro(msg):
        if ":" == msg.content[0] and ":" == msg.content[-1] and role in [userRoles.name for userRoles in msg.author.roles]:
            emoji_name = msg.content[1:-1]
            for emoji in msg.guild.emojis:
                if emoji_name == emoji.name:
                    await msg.channel.send(f"{msg.author.mention}{str(emoji)}")
                    await msg.delete()
```

Comment: How can i do it with multiple roles. Like `role = "-『』· -", "⠀⠀⠀⠀『』·  ", "⠀⠀⠀⠀『』· .. ", "⠀⠀⠀⠀『』· .. ", "⠀⠀⠀⠀『』· .. "`

Comment: try `any(rolesList in [userRoles.name for userRoles in msg.author.roles])`